# Regex - match third number before a character

Tags: perl, regex

I have this string:

```
/dev/sda1      23G   46G  47G  22%
```

And want to match only the integer in `47`'s place.

I tried modifying the "match second set of numbers" example (i.e.,`\d+[^\d*](\d+)`) here to make it match the third set (e.g., , http://perlmeme.org/faqs/regexp/regexp.html,  but I can't get a match.

Any idea how to match only the integer in `47`'s place?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a verbose example:

```perl
$string = '/dev/sda1      23G   46G  47G  22%';

my ( $number ) = $string =~ m|^/[\S]+/[\S]+\s+\d+\w\s+\d+\w\s+(\d+)|;

print $number;
```

Or if you'd like to see the regex more spread out:

```perl
my $string = '/dev/sda1      23G   46G  47G  22%';

my ( $number ) = $string =~ m|
        ^/[\S]+/[\S]+\s+    # drive
        \d+\w\s+        # first number - ignored
        \d+\w\s+        # second number - ignored
        (\d+)           # third number - CAPTURED
    |x;

print "$number\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

`^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\d+)` would do the trick, but I'd recommend splitting on whitespace and taking the fourth group, instead.

Comment: That worked nicely, thank you.  I upvoted but it's not public yet because I don't have enough reputation. Can you elaborate how the splitting whitespace method would work?

Comment: Something like `print split(/\s+/, $str)[3]` would, I think, do the trick.